# How can I containerize a command that takes a filename as an argument?

Tags: docker, command-line

I have a program written in C that takes two filenames as arguments, one as input and another as output. I would like to put this command-line program into a docker container for portability and consistency, and to be able to pass files from the host OS as command line arguments when the container is invoked.

That is, I have a program that is typically invoked:

```
progname inputfile outputfile
```

and I would like to be able to invoke it as:

```
docker [options] inputfile outputfile progname
```

in some order and have inputfile and outputfile refer to files on the host OS.

**How can I create a docker container that is able to take filenames on the host OS as arguments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to create is an image, i.e. the template for containers. You then want to mount the host OS volume when creating new containers with `docker run`. For that, check [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems). What you want to do is:

`docker run -itd -v <host_directory>/<filename>:<container_directory>/<filename> <image_name> <container_name> <cmd_or_shell_to_run>`

Comment: Could you expand on this, explaining what each of those pieces mean? This assumes a lot of knowledge of docker.

Comment: Which part needs expansion in your opinion? Would you need help on how to create the image? Regarding the `docker run` command, you can check the documentation page for help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/